# How to modify my CSS to create equal sized card components using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working to create equal-sized cards to fit my desired information. Currently it looks like this. I am using CSS flexbox. I tried a fix using align-items,however, that did not work. Will this be done using flex-grow?

[image]

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: auto;
}
```

```
import React from "react"

export default function Card(props){
    return(
        <div className="card">
            <h2>{props.name}</h2>
            <h2>{props.email}</h2>
            <h2>{props.phone}</h2>
            <h2>{props.website}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "./Components/Card"

const UserList = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([
    {
      id: "",
      email: "",
      website: "",
      phone: "",
      name: ""
    }
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
          {data.map((info) => {
            return <Card key={info.id} name={info.name} email={info.email} website={info.website} phone={info.phone}/>
          })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Flexbox is the wrong tool for that case. Flexbox is good for controlling either height or width but not both. If you need to control both, you should use css-grid.

Comment: Decide what width you want (% I would suggest) and then change `width: fit-content;`

Answer (score 0):

Give your width percentage like width: 25% instead of fit-content

Comment: yes i tried this and it worked! However, when i resize the window, the text overflows out of the card

Comment: To fix that you should use flexbox also in your card components or you can change font-size of card items in smaller screens with media query

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you whant set an equal width to the cards?

In that case you may try to add to your card:

```
.card {
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-basis: 0; 
  ... go on with your code
}
```

*Note: without working code example I cannot see how `width: fit-content` affect that settings. Maybe you have to remove it as well.*